# Don't run delegate method in didSelectRowAt

Tags: ios, swift, uitableview

*HogeViewController.swift*

```
protocol HogeDelegate: class {
  func huga()
}
class HogeViewController: UIViewController,UITableViewDelegate, UITableViewDataSource{
  weak var delegate:
  func tableView(didSelectRowAt){
    self.delegate?.huga()
  }
}
```

*HogeTableViewCell.swift*

```
class HogeTableViewCell: UITableViewCell, HogeDelegate{
  func huga(){
    print("huga")
  }
}
```

don't run this code...

Is this writing impossible?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Since the cell is variable it seems to be a specification that can not implement methods via delegate.

Answer (score 2):

`func tableView(didSelectRowAt)` isn't the signature of the `UITableViewDelegate`'s method, so no, it's never getting called. Your function's signature needs to be

`func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, didSelectRowAt rowIndex: Int)`

Even better, instead of having your class extend `UIViewController` and implement the `UITableView` data source and delegate, just make your class extend `UITableViewController`, which *already* implements the data source and delegate, and will thus force you to use the `override` modifier, like

`override func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, didSelectRowAt indexPath: IndexPath)`